# Tokens as a boilerplate?

Tags: tokens

Is there a Tokens module that allows for simple boilerplate embedding? For example, embedding `[notification 3]` into a node would correspond to an admin setting(`notification 3 = "Hello World"`). You would then have "Hello World" embedded into all nodes with `[notification 3]`.

Comment: How is this different from "regular" token usage?

Comment: I'm a new Drupal user, but from the Token page, "Note that Token module doesn't provide any visible functions to the user on its own, it just provides token handling services for other modules." So I'm assuming there's no UI that you can manage token assignments with.

Comment: I want to point out that there is a difference between creating a token, and having it replaced in use. I'm not sure if your question is regarding one, the other, or both, but kiamlaluno's answer gives you a good introduction to the possibilities you have.

Answer (score 6):

There is a module that replace some tokens accepted from the Token module (or implemented using `hook_token_info()` and `hook_tokens()` in Drupal 7) in the body of a node, the [Token Filter](http://drupal.org/project/token_filter) module.

> Token Filter is a very simple module to make token values available as an input filter.

There is then the [Token Node Tokens (TNT)](http://drupal.org/project/tokennodetokens) module that allows to define new tokens without implementing a module.

> TNT (Token Node Tokens) is a very simplistic module that allows you to create arbitrary tokens without having to create a custom module (i.e. /node/add/token). This was primarily created for use with the tokenize module so that through the UI a user could create tokens for use with CCK.

Unfortunately, this module has been declared unsupported, but looking at its code, you could create your custom module for doing the same thing.

An alternative is the [Custom Tokens](http://drupal.org/project/token_custom) module.

> It gives the user the ability to create custom tokens for specific replacements that can improve other modules relying on the Drupal 7 token API or, for Drupal 6, the Token module.
>
> Versions 7.x-1.x and previours relied on PHP evaluation to build custom tokens.
>
> The new 7.x-2.x relies on input filters. While still allowing for PHP tokens through the D7 core PHP filter module, administrators can permit only HTML or plain text custom tokens.

Comment: Thank you for this complete explanation! It really helped me.